# How to restrict Pull request approval in AWS Code Commit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

we are using AWS CodeCommit
I am able to restrict developers merging to master and  develop via below  IAM policy

But how can I restrict to group of people ( leads ) to approve pullrequest and another group to merge after approval.

```
  {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "codecommit:GitPush",
            "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
            "codecommit:PutFile",
            "codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward",
            "codecommit:CreatePullRequest"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:XXXXXXXXXX:XX-xx-reponame",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                "codecommit:References": [
                    "refs/heads/master",
                    "refs/heads/develop"
                ]
            },
            "Null": {
                "codecommit:References": false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/2794